# Empirical Density in R given posterior distribution

Tags: inference, density-function, posterior

I am trying to solve the problem where I have calculated posterior distribution **f(p|x) = *Be*(23,8)** and **prior f(p) = *Be*(1,1)**, given the n = 29 and x = 22.
representing the comparison by using

```
results<-binogcp(22,29, density="beta",params=c(1,1),n.pi= 1e4)
```

[image]

Can I represent the empirical density of sample size of *n* (1000) from the posterior distribution of ***p***, comparing it on the same graph with the prior and a posterior density of p?

Comment: Why sample from the posterior at all when you have already calculated it exactly?

Comment: I want to take new sample from posterior

Comment: Re your question "Can I represent...": Why not?  What stops you from estimating and plotting *any* empirical density on this graph?

Comment: I am not able to find a way to plot in r language new to r